# Python ctypes loads dll library without error but does not return expected results upon function call

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I'm trying to get my hands dirty with writing a Python 3.8.2 wrapper around an anti-virus vendor's serverapi.dll. They offer some C snippets that show how to use it in C/C++, and I'm trying to adapt that code to Python Ctypes. I have no control over the DLL--I can only load it and attempt to call the functions. I've pasted their code into Visual Studio, compiled it, and watched it return as they say it should.

The vendor's code that I'd like to adapt:

```
HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary(L"ServerApi.dll");
if (!hMod)
{
    std::cout << "Cannot load library error. Last error is:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
era_init_lib init_lib = (era_init_lib)GetProcAddress(hMod, "era_init_lib");
if (!init_lib)
{
    std::cout << "Cannot init library" << std::endl;
    FreeLibrary(hMod);
    return 1;
}
...
int res = init_lib();
if (res)
{
    std::cout << "Init lib result:" << res << std::endl;
    FreeLibrary(hMod);
    return 1;
}
```

The typedef of era_init_lib:

```
typedef int(*era_init_lib)();
```

My Pythonic attempt:

```
from ctypes import *

serverapi = WinDLL('../lib/ServerApi.dll')
era_init = serverapi.era_init_lib
era_init.restype = c_int
era_init.argtypes = None

res = era_init()
print("init code: " + str(res)) // prints "init code: 2"
```

The problem with my attempt is that it runs without Python errors, but it has the wrong return code. When I compile the above C code, the era_init_lib() returns 0 as it should, and the library is ready for use. When I run my python code, it runs a code of 2. According to the sparse documentation on this module, the possible return codes are:

```
Return value:
ERA_SUCCESS                     0
ERA_INVALID_ARGUMENT            1
ERA_NOT_INITIALIZED             3
```

2 is suspiciously missing from that list which leads me to believe that Python is loading this library incorrectly.

Things that I've tried:

- I think this is a Windows calling convention DLL, but I've tried loading it with CDLL. No change, no python error/stack trace/same return code.
- I've verified that the DLL is x64 and that my Python interpreter is x64.
- I had procmon running while the python code executes. It seems to load all of the dependency DLLs as my rudimentary understanding would expect
- I tried to wrap the functions that the C code is using to load it. No avail, but here's the attempt:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes

windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress.argtypes = [wintypes.HMODULE, wintypes.LPCSTR]
windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress.restype = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int)
init_lib = windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress(wdll, "era_init_lib".encode("cp1252"));
init_lib.restype = c_int

print(str(init_lib())) // Prints "2"
```

- I tried to prototype the function to no avail with:

```
era_init_proto = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int)
era_init = era_init_proto(("era_init_lib", serverapi), None)
```

TL;DR: Works as C code, but Python Ctypes function call doesn't behave as expected.

Anyone have any idea on where to go next?

Comment: There is only one calling convention in x64 `WinDLL` and `CDLL` are the same.  There's nothing wrong with your approach.  Is procmon showing the same DLLs being loaded, pathwise?

Comment: Good to know! Kind of on the ProcMon front. Visual Studio gives a list out of the DLLs loading in order as the program executes. I checked that list against ProcMon, and it seems like the list is out of order. The Python code loads ws2_32.dll well before it attempts serverapi.dll. The C code loads serverapi.dll first, and ws2_32.dll is the third thing it loads. Diving deeper on ProcMon, I checked near the end of its logs and everything that loaded in the C code, was loaded and attached to the python.exe process. Paths are always the same in either language--C:\windows\system32 for most of them

Comment: @MarkTolonen After you asked about ProcMon, I was going through and looking closer at the results. I noticed that there's a network.dll that serverapi.dll depends on, and it would would only look at C:\Python\Python38\network.dll. It wouldn't search the system path or the project location. Out of curriousity, I put that network.dll at the path above, and everything worked! Now the question of how to make it search the paths correctly to find it with the rest of the project files.

Comment: Welcome to DLL Hell :)

Comment: I wonder why you have network.dll in the Python38 directory.  My installation doesn't have it.

Comment: Network.dll is a dependency shipped along with that serverapi.dll. I had it in the same folder as serverapi along with the two other dlls that needed to load. Python was able load 3 of the 4 libraries correctly, but for some reason, it would not use the normal search paths to find network.dll. It would only check the python38 folder.   My next plan is to look into how ctypes searches for libraries and try to manually set my libs folder as something that it should be searching.